# load unknown number of external images without XML

Tags: actionscript-3

I need to know how to load unknown number of images from external folder without using XML

help me please,
thank you

Comment: local folder, remote folder? What have you tried? have you looked at the flash documentation on flash.filesystem.File?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i try to load external images from local folder.

Comment: @Nesrin Is your project for Web or Desktop(air)?

Comment: I am working in desktop application and i need to make gallery from external folder containing the images but i am not knowing the number of this images because the number may be changed every time, so i need to know how to load them into the appliaction

Comment: You can use the File system to read a directory and get the files that is in that directory. If the external folder is somewhere online than this won't work. (Is the folder online?)

Answer (score 1):

So from your comments I'm assuming this is an AIR Application, so you can access the filesystem via `File` class.

First of all, you need to get a `File` object that points to your folder, the easiest way is to hardcode it. A slightly more complex approach would involve opening a dialog, where the user can select his desired folder (using [`File.browseForOpen`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#browseForOpen%28%29)).

Let's take the easy route and define a constant path to the folder, here it's a folder called "images" in the users documents folder:

```
File imageFolder = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("images");
```

Once we have a folder instance, we can use the `getDirectoryListing` method to list all files within that folder. Here's an example:

```
// create a vector that will contain all our images
var images:Vector.<File> = new Vector.<File>();

// first, check if that folder really exists
if(imageFolder.exists && imageFolder.isDirectory){
    var files:Array = imageFolder.getDirectoryListing();

    for each(var file:File in files){
        // match the filename against a pattern, here only files
        // that end in jpg, jpeg, png or gif will be accepted
        if(file.name.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i)){
            images.push(file);
        }
    }
}

// at this point, the images vector will contain all image files
// that were found in the folder, or nothing if no images were found
// or the folder didn't exist.
```

To load the files into your application, you can do something like this:

```
for each(var file:File in images){
    // use a FileStream to read the file data into a ByteArray
    var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    stream.open(file, FileMode.READ);
    var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    stream.readBytes(bytes);
    stream.close();

    // create a loader and load the image into it
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();

    // use the loadBytes method to read the data
    loader.loadBytes(bytes);

    // you can add the loader to the scene, so that it will be visible.
    // These loaders will all be at 0, 0 coordinates, so maybe change 
    // the x and y coordinates to something more meaningful/useful.
    this.addChild(loader);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate a little bit better the question? If it's a user action (i.e. the user needs to upload some photos) I'd use the [File API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html) - you can see examples [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cf6.html) - otherwise, if it's from the server side I'd use a PHP or Phyton script.

Comment: I am working in desktop application and i need to make gallery from external folder containing the images but i am not knowing the number of this images because the number may be changed every time, so i need to know how to load them into the appliaction

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your application is **Air (Desktop application)**, this code will be useful:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" creationComplete="init()">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            public function init():void{
                var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
                var f:File = new File("c:/imgTest.jpg");
                var b:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                fs.open(f, FileMode.READ);
                fs.readBytes(b,0,fs.bytesAvailable);
                idImg.source  = b;
                fs.close();
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:Image id="idImg" width="100%" height="100%"/>
</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

Place an image in **c:/imgTest.jpg**. Note that this image is outside from your project path. 
You have other options to load images, but these must be accessible by URL, or should be in the path of the project.
Here a links that will be usefull for load images in Flex Air and Web:

- [Working with File objects in AIR](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7fe4.html#WS2A7C0A31-A6A9-42d2-8772-79166A98A085)
- [Image as ByteArray in Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3192998/1563878)
- [Image Control](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSc5cd04c102ae3e97-33ad5caa12c719dc7c8-8000.html)
- [Programatically load images in Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1864786/1563878).

**Note**: i tried only with **JPG** files, i do not know if this works with other types.