# How do I get the list of images in a specific folder CameraRoll. To load in my application

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I am developing an application in AIR / AS3 and do not want to use the native Device image selection screen, must receive the list to create thumbnails within my application (Ex: Instagram). Help me please

Comment: Simple Google search gives you tons of answers http://stackoverflow.com/a/17940578/3623547

Comment: @kare Hello, I came to test this code. On the computer, it correctly returns all files in the documents folder. But when I compile my app, nothing is returned. Seems not to have access to "documentsDirectory" - know what can it be?

Will the error be in this first line of code?

var docsImages: File = File.documentsDirectory;
var getfiles: Array = docsImages.getDirectoryListing ();

Answer (score 0):

This is tested to select any jpg images in certain folder 
in this case "imgs" folder in the sd card

```
import flash.filesystem.File;


var ROOT: File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("imgs/"); /// the directory to read from in the sd card
var FILES: Array ;// = ROOT.getDirectoryListing();
var fileArr: Array = new Array;


getSubfiles();


function getSubfiles() {
    if (ROOT.exists) {
         FILES = ROOT.getDirectoryListing();
        for (var i: int = 0; i < FILES.length; i++) {
            var File_Ext: String;

            File_Ext = "" + FILES[i].extension;

            if (File_Ext.toLowerCase() == "jpg") {
                fileArr.push(FILES[i].name);
            }
        }
        trace(fileArr);
    } else {
        trace("Folder not existed");
    }
}
```

don't forget to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

to your manifest

Comment: Hello @kare. implemented its code in Android and it worked perfectly. Thank you! BUT, I need to modify to run on iOS? Testie some folder, and cóigo always returns "non-existent folder." I would like to specifically access the "Camera Roll". I'm waiting for your return and thank you A LOT!